# Curl difference between data from file and direct input

Tags: rest, csv, curl, post

I am posting data using curl to a JAX-RS REST API that accepts CSV.

This command works fine:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d '
"name","age"
"Abe","35"
"Bob","40"
' $url
```

and I can see the data reaching the API.

However, if I keep the data in a file called payload.csv and post like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' -d @payload.csv $url
```

the data doesn't reach the API. What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

Figured I need to post the file data using `--data-binary`, so like this:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' --data-binary @payload.csv $url
```

From [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --data-binary
>
> (HTTP) This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing
>   whatsoever.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a
>   filename. Data is posted in a similar manner as -d, --data does,
>   except that newlines and carriage returns are preserved and
>   conversions are never done.

So `-d` option strips newlines and carriage returns when posting a file!